# Get insights for facebook page video (not post)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am uploading videos to a page as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads

This gives me a specific ID that identifies that video. The video is also "posted" to the page feed automatically.

However, I cannot get insights for that post using the Page Video Posts metrics (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights#page_video_posts). The video itself is (logically) not recognized as a post and as such does not have an `insights` edge.

Is there some way to get metrics for a video on a page from the video ID itself? I know there are restrictions (must be page, 30+ likes, etc.), but these have all been fulfilled.

It seems somewhat backwards to have to upload a video, suppress the video auto-posting and then make an actual post with the video in it to get the insights for that post (and why is the video statistics related to the post instead of the video?!).

I am using python, but really any examples showing the actual requests being made will be helpful.

Comment: I believe that this is not currently supported. As per the documentation you can only see the stats of a video attributed to a post